# java.net.http.HttpRequest not sending "Authorization:" header - why?

Tags: java, http, http-headers, basic-authentication, java-17

I'm trying to download an image from a HTTP camera. The problem is, the camera in question requires (basic) authentication. I know basic auth should not be used over HTTP, but we're talking about an isolated network, so that's not the point here.

I'm trying to use Java17 native java.net.http.HttpClient for this. I'm using the following code:

```
protected BufferedImage retrieveImage(URI uri) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    log.trace("Using authorization header of '{}'", basicAuthString);
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                     .uri(uri)
                                     .header("Authorization", basicAuthString)
                                     .GET()
                                     .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                                     .build();
    return retrieveImage(request);
}

private BufferedImage retrieveImage(HttpRequest request) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HttpResponse<byte[]> response = null;
    try {
        response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());
    } catch (ConnectException ex) {
        log.error("Connection refused when downloading image from " + uri.toString());
        return null;
    }
    if (response.statusCode() != 200) { // ok
        log.error("Error retrieving image, status code is {}", response.statusCode());
        return null;
    }
    ByteArrayInputStream bis   = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.body());
    BufferedImage        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
    return image;
}
```

The HttpClient variable (client in the above code) is created by:

```
            this.client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                                .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
                                .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                        return new PasswordAuthentication(camera.getLogin(), camera.getPassword().toCharArray());
                                    }
                                })
                                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                                .build();
```

Since I'm using Basic authorization, I can pre-calculate the auth header and store it internally. And this code is executed, as in the logs I can see the following:

```
2022-05-04 12:40:00.183 [TRACE] [pool-2-thread-78]     Retrieving image from http://<censored>:7020/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/1/picture
2022-05-04 12:40:00.183 [TRACE] [pool-2-thread-78]     Using authorization header of 'Basic <censored>'
2022-05-04 12:40:00.491 [ERROR] [pool-2-thread-78]     Error retrieving image, status code is 401
```

However, what actually gets sent over TCP does not include the Authorization header. The following is a "Follow TCP" dump from Wireshark:

```
GET /ISAPI/Streaming/channels/1/picture HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Host: <censored>:7020
User-Agent: Java-http-client/17.0.3

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 04 May 2022 12:39:59 GMT
Server: webserver
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 178
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth", realm="<censored>", nonce="<censored>", stale="FALSE"

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Document Error: Unauthorized</title></head>
<body><h2>Access Error: 401 -- Unauthorized</h2>
<p>Authentication Error</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know the response asks for Digest authorization, and I'm using Basic. That's not the point, the camera supports basic authorization as well. **The point is, the "Authorization:" header is not even sent with the request.**

It's hard to find any good guides for using Java17 native HttpClient, as most of them cover the Apache one. I found one from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client), but it covers the Java9. The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html#header(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) is of little help, either. I am also using Authenticator, as Baeldung suggested, but it doesn't kick in, either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. It seems the new HttpClient does not support Digest authentication out of the box. See here: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8285888

The suggested way is to implement digest authentication yourself on application level.

Comment: As I said above, the problem is not with the Digest authentication. The problem is that the  Authorization header is not being sent at all with the request. If the original request contains the Basic authentication data in the header, the request is processed and the camera doesn't ask for Digest authentication. The problem is, this was done using Apache's HttpClient, and I wanted to do this using the JDK one.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post.

Comment: Did you try setting a global ``Authenticator.setDefault(...)`` instead of setting the authenticator per request?